# Using Laravel 9 to update and delete test not passing the test

Tags: laravel

I have have created a feature test to make sure that my controllers work as expexted, but for some reason the test keeps on failing, im getting this error message
Missing required parameter for [Route: admin/suppliers/destroy] [URI: admin/suppliers/{supplier}] [Missing parameter: supplier].

i have added the parameter to the route: route('admin/suppliers/destroy', $supplier),
but i still get the same error, Does anyone have a idea on what could create this error

Here is my test

```
public function test_if_a_user_can_delete_a_supplier()
{
    //Make fake data, don't persist to database.
    $supplier = Supplier::factory()->make()->setAppends([])->makeHidden(['created_at', 'updated_at']);

    //Create an Admin User and assign the Administrator role to this new user
    $adminUser = factory(AdminUser::class)->create();
    $adminUser->roles()->sync(Role::where('name', 'Administrator')->first());

    $this->actingAs($adminUser, config('admin-auth.defaults.guard'))
        ->json(
            'DELETE',
            route('admin/suppliers/destroy', $supplier),
            $supplier->toArray()
        )
        ->assertStatus(302)
        ->assertRedirectToRoute('admin/suppliers/index');
    $this->assertDatabaseMissing(
        'suppliers',
        $supplier->toArray()

    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```php
> //Make fake data, don't persist to database.
>  $supplier = Supplier::factory()->make()->setAppends([])->makeHidden(['created_at', 'updated_at']);
> ```

You are not persisting the `Supplier` model to the database.

If route model binding is used in the controller method for the route `'admin/suppliers/destroy'`, then `route('admin/suppliers/destroy', $supplier)` will return `HTTP 404 Not Found`, which would your test fail because you are expecting an `HTTP 302 Found` response.

Also, when passing a variable to the route, it tries to get the model's id. Since you didn't persist `$supplier` to the database, it has no id. This probably causes the error you see

> Missing required parameter for [Route: `admin/suppliers/destroy`] [URI: `admin/suppliers/{supplier}`] [Missing parameter: `supplier`].

---

Even without the `$this->actingAs(...)` statement, your `$this->assertDatabaseMissing(...)` would pass, so your test isn't actually testing what it's supposed to test.

---

I'd rewrite the test like this:

```php
public function test_if_an_admin_user_can_delete_a_supplier()
{
    // ARRANGE
    $supplier = Supplier::factory()->create(['name' => 'Fake Supplier']);
    $admin_role = Role::where('name', 'Administrator')->first();
    $admin_user = AdminUser::factory()->has($admin_role)->create();
    // Some people like to place a "pre-assertion" to make sure the Act phase is the reason changes occurred. In this case, it would look like this
    // $this->assertDatabaseHas('suppliers', ['name' => 'Fake Supplier']);

    // ACT
    $response = $this->actingAs($admin_user, config('admin-auth.defaults.guard'))
        ->deleteJson(route('admin/suppliers/destroy', $supplier), [
            'name' => 'Fake Supplier', /* using this or $supplier->name comes down to choice */
        ]);

    // ASSERT
    $response->assertStatus(302)
             ->assertRedirectToRoute('admin/suppliers/index');

    $this->assertDatabaseMissing('suppliers', [
        'name' => 'Fake Supplier', /* using this or $supplier->name comes down to choice */
    ]);
}
```

And some things could still be refactored. Like for example, making this

```php
$admin_role = Role::where('name', 'Administrator')->first();
$admin_user = AdminUser::factory()->has($admin_role)->create();
```

into one line using factory states. And if it's a line that repeats in a lot of tests in your test class, then making it a property as part of the `setUp()` method.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your comment, you have really helped me allot, when do you use the create and make when testing your controllers ? im still learning so just wan to know when to use them and when not to

Comment: If the test doesn't depend on the model being in the database, I use make. For example, testing accessors and mutators. In this test, you are asserting against the database so you pretty much need to use create. When in doubt, use create.

Comment: Thank you IGP your comments really helped me understand the concept, there is so much wrong information out there that leads you to 100 of question and 200 errors, i actually get it now